# Creating OpenSSL dll in Windows using MinGW64

Tags: dll, openssl, mingw-w64

I am trying to build OpenSSL for my project in Windows. I am using MinGW64 for this. However, when trying to build shared libraries OpenSSL dll.a are still archive files. I configure OpenSSL as follows:

```
Configure --cross-compile-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --install-prefix=C:\install --prefix=/openssl-1.0.1e shared no-idea no-rc5 no-mdc2 mingw64
```

I am hoping someone could help me with what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe OpenSSL supports the configuration.

`Configure` has `MinGW64` target, but it looks like it only builds static archive.

```
# MinGW
"mingw", "gcc:-mno-cygwin -DL_ENDIAN -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -fomit-frame-pointer 
-O3 -march=i486 -Wall::-D_MT:MINGW32:-lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lcrypt32:BN_LLONG 
${x86_gcc_des} ${x86_gcc_opts} EXPORT_VAR_AS_FN:${x86_asm}:coff:win32:
cygwin-shared:-D_WINDLL -DOPENSSL_USE_APPLINK:-mno-cygwin:.dll.a",
...
"mingw64", "gcc:-mno-cygwin -DL_ENDIAN -O3 -Wall -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DUNICODE 
-D_UNICODE::-D_MT:MINGW64:-lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lcrypt32:SIXTY_FOUR_BIT RC4_CHUNK_LL 
DES_INT EXPORT_VAR_AS_FN:${x86_64_asm}:mingw64:win32:cygwin-shared:-D_WINDLL:
-mno-cygwin:.dll.a",
```

But I think it should be invoked as:

```
perl Configure mingw64 no-shared no-asm --prefix=/C/install
```

You can copy/paste the `mingw64` target and turn knobs on it, if you'd like. I often copy a similar target when cross compiling.

[OpenSSL for Windows](http://www.blogcompiler.com/2011/12/21/openssl-for-windows/) might also be helpful.